# xulrunner: where is install-app.py

Tags: installation, xulrunner

I am trying to use xulrunner --install-app but it seems to be obsolete as I get the message

"--install-app support has been removed. Use 'python install-app.py' instead."

Where is this install-app.py?

Comment: +1 (where is the "follow this/notify me" button?

Answer (score 2):

- Download the source of your release of XULRunner from here: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/
- Unzip it
- cd to: mozilla-release/xulrunner/app/install_app.py

Found it by looking at this patch:
https://bug747597.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8357649

Which was attached to this issue: [Bug 747597 - (install_app.py) Port XULRunner's --install-app to Python](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747597)